# Jenkins declarative pipeline parallel steps executors

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am migrating a job from multijob to a Jenkins Declarative pipeline job. I am unable to run the parallel steps on multiple executors.

For example in the pipeline below, I see only one executor being used when I run the pipeline.

I was wondering why only a single executor is used. The idea is that each parallel step would be inoking a make target that would build a docker image.

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('build libraries') {
      agent { label 'master' }
      steps {
        parallel(
          "nodejs_lib": {
            dir(path: 'nodejs_lib') {
                sh 'sleep 110'
            }
          },
          "python_lib": {
            dir(path: 'python_lib') {
              sh 'sleep 100'
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
  options {
    ansiColor('gnome-terminal')
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '30'))
    timestamps()
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute the step in multiple nodes?

Comment: well, I am trying to run the two parallel steps on two different executors on the same Jenkins master. The sleep commands in actual use case are two docker build commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following way to perform parallel tasks execution for your pipeline job:

```
def tasks = [:]

            tasks["TasK No.1"] = {
              stage ("TASK1"){    
                node('master') {  
                    sh '<docker_build_command_here>'
                }
              }
            }
            tasks["task No.2"] = {
              stage ("TASK2"){    
                node('master') {  
                    sh '<docker_build_command_here>'
                }
              }
            }
            tasks["task No.3"] = {
              stage ("TASK3"){    
                node('remote_node') {  
                    sh '<docker_build_command_here>'
                }
              }
            }

 parallel tasks
```

If you want to execute parallel tasks on a single node and also want to have the same workspace for both the tasks then you can go with the following approach:

```
node('master') { 

def tasks = [:]

                tasks["TasK No.1"] = {
                  stage ("TASK1"){    

                        sh '<docker_build_command_here>'
                  }
                }
                tasks["task No.2"] = {
                  stage ("TASK2"){    

                        sh '<docker_build_command_here>'
                  }
                }


     parallel tasks       
}
```

Comment: will it take up two executors on jenkins or one?

Comment: The number parallel tasks = numbers of executors.

Comment: I see that each "node" uses an executor on that "node". But how do you make the "task 1" and "task 2" running on "master" use the same workspace?

Comment: You can use `External Workspace Manager` Plugin to achieve that.
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#external-workspace-manager

Comment: @puneeth I have updated my answer. I have included another script using that you can use same workspace for multiple tasks without using any plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering what is more performance efficient. In the first solution, each task takes up an executor on the node and hence, in total 3 executors. In the second solution, both the tasks run on a single executor on master and thereby taking 1 executor in total:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152604/discussion-between-anil-mahapatra-official-and-puneeth).

Comment: If there is a single node say master, how to force each parallel tasks to use 1 executor ? Using the second method i see parallel tasks in pipeline gui but in the backend the tasks happen in serial.